# Unable to set val of hidden input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this following code, I am trying to set value of hidden field with java script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var currentTime = new Date();
var tday=currentTime.getDate();
var tmonth=currentTime.getMonth();
var tyear=currentTime.getFullYear();

$("input[name='tday'").val(tday);
$('#tmonth').val(tmonth);
$('#tyear').val(tyear);
document.getElementById('tday').value='213';




</script>
<div id="edit_bs" class="edit_bs_st">
<form id='edir_pers' class='edit_pers_css' name='edit_pers' action='edit_pers.php' method='post'>

<input id='tyear' name='tyear'/>
<input id='tmonth' type='hidden' name='tmonth'  />
<input id='tday' type='hidden' name='tday' />

<button type="submit">Submit</button></from>
```

The problem is that the value are not being passed to the 'edit_pers.php' they are blank. I have even tried document.getlementid.value to set the value but nothing works. I dont know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: The fields don't exist yet. Either move the script below the elements or use `$(document).ready`

Answer (score 2):

`hidden` doesn't have anything to do with it. It's your call to the element that is bad.

**THIS IS YOURS: BROKEN**

```
$("input[name='tday'").val(tday);
```

**THIS IS FIXED**

```
$('input[name=tday]').val(tday);
```

Here's the result.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

   var currentTime = new Date();
   var tday=currentTime.getDate();
   $('input[name=tday]').val(tday);
}):
```

---

As a side note, you don't need the redundant identifiers in your code. I'd personally go with this since you are probably required to have the `name` attribute.

**HTML**

```
<input type='hidden' name='tday' />
```

**Javascript**

```
 $('input[name=tday]').val(tday);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Uh7yn/

Comment: In addition to this, your (OP) sample is missing a closing bracket.  `$("input[name='tday'").val(tday);` should be `$("input[name='tday']").val(tday);`

Comment: yeahhh... I have tried bot java script and jquery but none on them work.

Comment: Thanks  daughtkom. I changed it ...still no change :(

Comment: @daughtkom I'm pretty sure the extra quotes are not necessary. Please see the edited answer to see my approach ([working jsfiddle example included](http://jsfiddle.net/Uh7yn/))

Comment: thanks @Chase Florell .... I m still not very good at jquery ;)..... Thanks for helping.

Comment: @user2288650, have you read the comment above that indicates that you're calling the script before the controls are created?  In addition to fixing the missing bracket, you must ensure that this code runs after the controls are created by either moving the script after the controls or putting in document.ready.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell I believe you're right about quotes.  I am guilty of copy/paste in my comment.  :)

Answer (score 0):

A part of your problem is that your code runs before the elements exists in the DOM.

Since you are using jQuery, the best way to circumvent this issue would be to use the `document.ready` handler. However, you will have to make sure that `jQuery` is loaded on the page.

```
$(function () {
    //since your inputs have ids, you do not have to use any attribute selectors
    $('#tday').val(213);
});
```

Also, you have a typo in the closing `form` tag.